# Persist a variable for the entire application in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working on an application which aims to display records of students, obviously to see and edit a record I have to select a student.
I would like to know how to store the id of the student in a global variable or something like that. To make it available in any part of the application to use it from any controller or view and once the user of the application close or display another record this variable is loaded with the new Id

Any idea how I could do this

Comment: Use sessions. Check laravel docs

Comment: "Use from any controller or view" begins to go down a dark path.. it's much better to explicitly maintain the context of the record being edited (which is different from the context of the current user, for which a session is suited). Going down this 'global' route ends at an old spaghetti factory with confused and tired workers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the concept and idea.
Considering that you are storing each student data and each student must has username and password for logging in to their account.

So get the id of the authenticated user like

```
Auth::student()->id; // For logged in user we do Auth::user()->id;
```

Now what you want is to share this ID globally and accessible to all controller and views, for this you need to edit `AppServiceProvider` and in the boot function grab the authenticated user and share it globally as below.

```
public function boot()
{
        $studentID = Auth::student()->id; // grab the ID you want to share globally
        view()->share('studentID', $studentID);
}
```

Make sure you add import the model you are using.

Now you can access the authenticated student ID any where like this

```
{{ $studentID }} //this will echo the authenticated student ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the globally available `session` function:

```
session(['studentID'=>Auth::student()->id]);
```

Then access it like this:

```
session('studentID');
```

And in the view:

```
{{ session('studentID') }}
```

Comment: Which file / route do you put this handy code snipett in?

Comment: @Glen you can put this in any controller.  It will be persisted to the session without having to explicitly return it. You can use it throughout the lifetime of that user session.